# Mock prototype scoped bean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have two beans:

```
@Component
public class StudentServices {

    // ... member variables, etc.

    @Lookup
    public SchoolNotification getNotification() {
        return null;
    }

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

And the second bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SchoolNotification {
    // ... prototype-scoped state
}
```

I need help to write a unit test for StudentServices that will somehow mock SchoolNotification.

Mockito.mock does not work because the two beans have different scopes and every time StudentServices.getNotification() is executed the spring context provides a new instance of SchoolNotification.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, this was fixed with a Spy.

Something like this:

@Component
public class StudentServicesTest {

```
@Mock
SchoolNotification schoolNotification; 
@Spy
@InjectMock
private StudentServices studentServices;


@Before
public void setUp(){
   doReturn(null).when(studentServices).getSchoolNotification();
   //If you want to return something else then
  doReturn(schoolNotification).when(studentServices).getSchoolNotification();
}

@Test
public void testOtherMethods(){
    //Prepare other when/doReturs/etc
    //Test other method using studentServices
    //list of assertions
}
```

}

Comment: @user1767316 sure, I edited my response to show the code that I used back then. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you @user1532449, I will have a look if it would have helped in my case, I am sure your code will help those stucked to test and understand your answer. I make use of '@SpyBean' in my code and do not use '@InjectMock' I'll have a look at it